# Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot bar, but I have the de problem with the data. Data is from a "list" and I converted "list" to "data frame", but I have several problems. First is the spaces after the word like this "`Sources`       " and I think also after the Sources "B                       ". When I run the code I have the error: Error in abs(x).
I would be glad to know what is going on as I am unable to make the graph. I think the problem might be in these spaces.

Codes

```
S <- summary(object = results, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
df <- S$MostRelSources
df <- df %>% dplyr::rename(Sources = `Sources       `)
df$Sources <- as.character(df$Sources))
df$Articles <- as.numeric(df$Articles)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Sources, y=Articles)) +
          geom_col()

Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Data

```
dput(df)
    structure(list(Sources = structure(c("A                           ", 
    "B                       ", "C                   ", 
    "D                  ", "E            ", 
    "F                           ", "G", 
    "H                              ", "Y                         ", 
    "J                           "), class = "AsIs"), 
        Articles = c(1, 10, 7, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute `"AsIs"` possibly from a remnant of `list` column created.  We can reconvert it back to `character` with `as.character` and now the code works

```
df$Sources<- as.character(trimws(df$Sources))
```

-testing

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Sources, y=Articles)) +
           geom_col()
```

-output

[image]